# Is Gift tax due on transfer of USD and mutual funds from non US citizen brother outside USA to sister, Permanent Resident in USA?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, gift-tax, family

My sister is in USA for many years, as a permanent resident. I wish to send her about 150K $ as gift from my bank account abroad. I am an Indian citizen. These funds are from my savings while working in United Arab Emirates for many years. Another 150K $ is in International mutual fund investments. Can I gift her these also, with out US tax liability for her? What is she required to declare to IRS?